# Calling delete on std::stack of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have a `std::stack` which has some pointers inside:

```
std::stack<State*> m_states;
```

When I initialize my program, I call `new` to push an item onto the stack (it must be a pointer because I will use polymorphic types).

Is this the correct way of deleting with all the stuff?

Here is where I call new (`GameState` and MenuStates`are classes inherited from`State`):

```cpp
m_states.push(new GameState());
m_states.push(new MenuState());
```

And this is what I have in the destructor of the whole App class:

```cpp
while (!m_states.empty())
{
    delete m_states.top(); // (*)
    m_states.pop();
}
```

Should I only call (*), or do I need to `pop()` as well?

Comment: Better to use a `unique_ptr` and not have to deal with cleanup at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Should I only call (*) or do I need to pop as well?*

Well, if you *don't* call `pop()` in the `while` loop, then how will that loop ever end? In other words, how will the condition, `!m_states.empty()` ever become `false`?

There are other container types (like `std::vector`) where you *could* just run through each member, deleting the pointed-to object, and then clear the container, but you can't do that with the `std::stack` container. That is to say, there is no `[]` operator for a stack – you can only access the top element.